# Python 3.4 Radioisotope Decay using functions, lists and, loops

Tags: python-3.x

Could someone help me figure out how to trace decay activity day by day. I believe I need an open list somewhere. Here is the equation, `Ad = Ad - 1*e - (decayConstant / isotope-half-life)`, where:

- `Ad` is the isotope activity at the end of day `d`,
- `Ad-1` is the isotope previous activity at the end of day `d-1` (the previous day),
- and `A0` is the initial activity.

Therefore, the activity at the end of day 1 is `A1 = A0 * e -(decayConstant / isotope-half-life)`, at the end of day 2,
`A2 = A1 * e - (decayConstant / isotope-half-life)`, and so on.

```
import math
import time  

#create and initialize variables and constants
decay_constant = 0.693
disposal_constant = 37


#process
def main():
        isotope = 0
        while isotope != 3:

            #input
            print("Please choose an isotope to calculate or exit")
            print("Type 1 for Chromium-51")
            print("Type 2 for Phosphorus-32")
            print("Type 3 to quit the program")
            isotope = int(input("Please input your choice now."))


            if isotope == 1:
                chromium()

            elif isotope == 2:
                phosphorus()

            elif isotope == 3:
                print("Goodbye.")

            else:
                print("Please try again.")

#Define function for Chromium
def chromium():
    half_life = 27.7025
    Ao = float(input("Please input initial activity of the 
radioisotope(kBq):"))
    M_total = float(input("Please enter the total mass of the 
 radioisotope(kg):"))
    M_percent = float(input("Please enter the percent mass of the 
radioisotope present:"))
    Ad = int(input("Please enter a numerical start date:"))
    mass = M_total * (1-(M_percent/100))
    days = get_days_to_safe_level(Ao,mass,half_life)
    safe_level_days = safe_activity_level(Ao,safe_activity_level,half_life)
    activity = new_isotope_activity(Ad,decay_constant,half_life)

#Define function for Phosphorus
def phosphorus():
    half_life = 14.262
    Ao = float(input("Please input initial activity of the radioisotope:"))
    M_total = float(input("Please enter the total mass of the 
radioisotope:"))
    M_percent = float(input("Please enter the percent mass of the 
radioisotope   present:"))
    Ad = input("Please enter a numerical start date:")
    mass = M_total * (1-(M_percent/100))
    days = get_days_to_safe_level(Ao,mass,half_life)
    safe = safe_activity_level(Ao,safe_activity_level,half_life)
    activity = new_isotope_activity(Ad,decay_constant,half_life)

#output
    print("It takes", format(days,'.4f'), "days to reach safe level.")
    print("Final Activity: ", format(safe_activity_level,'.2f'),"kBq")
    print(isotope, "Activity After","=", new_isotope_activity,days)


#Define function for Days to Safe Level
def get_days_to_safe_level(Ao,mass,half_life):
    days_to_safe_level = (-
  half_life/decay_constant)*math.log(disposal_constant/(Ao/mass))
    return days_to_safe_level

#Define function for Safe Activitiy Level
def safe_activity_level(Ao,days,half_life):
    safe_activity_level = Ao * math.e**(-(decay_constant*days/(half_life)))
    return safe_activity_level

#Define function for New Isotope Activity
def new_isotope_activity():
    Ad = Ad*math.e**(-(decay_constant/(half_life)))
    return new_isotope_activity


#call main function
main()
```

The way the code sits gives me an error, unsupported operand for 'float' and 'function'. 
Any help would be appreciated, thanks. I am in an intro to programming class so I apologize in advance for my lack of programming knowledge.

Comment: safe_activity_level = Ao * math.exp**-(decay_constant*days/half_life)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'function'
>>>

Comment: `math.exp` is a *function*, you need to *call it*.

Comment: I imported the math module before my main function.

Comment: Yes. You did. Now you need to *call the function it defines*, not try to multiply by it.

Comment: I took out the two asterisks in both places and I still get the same error message

Comment: Per your comment below you're now trying a bitwise operation on it. **You need to call it**: `math.exp(exponent)`. Also it would help if you'd [edit] to give a [mcve]. Also note that this is [shown in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.exp).

Comment: I don't think the OP understands what is meant by "call the function".

Comment: I think in my last edit I got it right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused as the variable days which is implemented in the `safe_activity_level` function. As its used to calculate the `safe_activity_level` with the expression: `Ao * math.e**(-(decay_constant*days/(half_life)))`.

```
def safe_activity_level(Ao,days,half_life):
safe_activity_level = Ao * math.e**(-(decay_constant*days/(half_life)))
return safe_activity_level
```

The variable `days` is not an integer or a string as wehn you call the variable you pass a function.

LINE 55:

```
safe = safe_activity_level(Ao,safe_activity_level,half_life)
```

the `safe_activity_level` is also the name of the function, therefore, its passing the function as the variable `days`.

FINALLY,
this means that the variable `days` is a function rather than an integer / a string as i stated before.

Hope i helped!

---

I cant reply yet as myy rep is below 50, but i would like to note that you call a function by adding `()`

This means, you should call math.exp by `math.exp(XXX)` instead of `math.exp**XXX`.

Comment: Safe_Activity_Level = Ao * e^-( decayConstant *Days_to_Safe_Lev el/ isotope-half-Life). -(decay_constant*days/half_life) should be an exponent here.